# CAPL Signal finding

Tags: capl

[image: Picture for signal Calling]

I am currently working on a project which involves using the CAN demo provided by Vector.

I am trying to Call on the value of a signal (WN_left_up) this usually works in reference to the message in which the signal is displayed. e.g

```
On message Console_1
{
    Console_1.WN_left_up = getvalue(this);
}
```

As you can see from the image when i try and find the signal it says that it is not linked to the message `Console_1`. However in the trace it clearly shows the signal inside the read out for `Console_1`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The attached picture does not appear to be reachable.

Comment: Please add more context info. What CANoe/CANalyzer version are you using? Which demo configuration?